# Azure policy not working on certain resources?

Tags: azure-policy

I am trying to set up a naming convention policy on some resources but it is not working.

The resources that don't work :

- SQL database : field type = Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases
- Function APP : field type = Microsoft.Web/sites
- SQL Server : field type = Microsoft.Sql/servers
- Azure machine learning workspace : field type = Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces
- Automation Account : field type = Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts
- Logic App : field type = Microsoft.Logic/workflows

Here is the script I use for all of them I just change the field type value and the name value :

```html
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
        },
        {
          "field": "name",
          "notLike": "st*"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and below is the result**

> **Note:** By default Azure won't accept any special character name ending with '.' or ' ', containing '<,>,*,%,&,:,,/,?' or control characters.

I have created a policy to restrict **Azure SQL Databases**, if the name does not match the policy naming convention.

```
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
},
{
"not": {
"anyOf": [
{
"field": "name",
"like": "st-"
}
]
}
}
]
},
"then": {
"effect": "deny"
}
},
"parameters": {}
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

I have created a policy to restrict **Azure Function APP**, if the name does not match the policy naming convention.

```
{
"mode": "All",
"policyRule": {
"if": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
},
{
"not": {
"anyOf": [
{
"field": "name",
"like": "st-"
}
]
}
}
]
},
"then": {
"effect": "deny"
}
},
"parameters": {}
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

For other resources also you can follow the same process.

```
- SQL Server : field type = Microsoft.Sql/servers
-  Azure machine learning workspace : field type = Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces
- Automation Account : field type = Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts
-  Logic App : field type = Microsoft.Logic/workflows
```